# The user presence return value is unreadable

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I am new to java, for several weeks I have been trying to report the status of a person via microsoft graph, I have no error but the returned value is unreadable. I must be missing something to show the status.
It's a Gradle Project in Eclipse
here is my code:

````
   ```public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    // <LoadSettingsSnippet>
    // Load OAuth settings
    final Properties oAuthProperties = new Properties();
    try {
        oAuthProperties.load(App.class.getResourceAsStream("oAuth.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to read OAuth configuration. Make sure you have a properly formatted oAuth.properties file. See README for details.");
        return;
    }

    final String appId = oAuthProperties.getProperty("app.id");
    final List<String> appScopes = Arrays
        .asList(oAuthProperties.getProperty("app.scopes").split(","));
    // </LoadSettingsSnippet>

    // Initialize Graph with auth settings
    Graph.initializeGraphAuth(appId, appScopes);
    final String accessToken = Graph.getUserAccessToken();

    // getpresence
    Presence teamCollectionPage = Graph.getPresence();
    System.out.println("Valeur Presence : " + teamCollectionPage);
    
 

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
````

``

```
  public class Graph {

private static GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = null;
private static TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = null;

public static void initializeGraphAuth(String applicationId, List<String> scopes) {
    // Create the auth provider
    final DeviceCodeCredential credential = new DeviceCodeCredentialBuilder()
        .clientId(applicationId)
        .challengeConsumer(challenge -> System.out.println(challenge.getMessage()))
        .build();

    authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, credential);

    // Create default logger to only log errors
    DefaultLogger logger = new DefaultLogger();
    logger.setLoggingLevel(LoggerLevel.ERROR);

    // Build a Graph client
    graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
        .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
        .logger(logger)
        .buildClient();
}

public static String getUserAccessToken()
{
    try {
        URL meUrl = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me");
        return authProvider.getAuthorizationTokenAsync(meUrl).get();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

public static Presence getPresence() {
    if (graphClient == null) throw new NullPointerException(
        "Graph client has not been initialized. Call initializeGraphAuth before calling this method");

    
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

    Presence presence = graphClient.users("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").presence()
        .buildRequest()
        .get();

    return presence ;
}
```

}

the message return is "Valeur Presence : com.microsoft.graph.models.Presence@4d411036"

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you’re seeing is the default value of `Object.toString` if the method isn’t overridden in the child class (and it isn’t for the `Presence` model class).

You can access the value explicitly, e.g.:

```
System.out.println("Valeur Presence : " + teamCollectionPage.availability);
```